# My program doesn't work properly and when I click 'add player' button, no docs add to mongo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor, preventdefault

I want to write a simple program to add players name on the screen and mongodb butI'm a beginner and I want to write a program in meteor for adding players to mongo, but when I click on add player button, the program doesn't work properly and no docs add to mongo:

```
import './main.html';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'
import {Players} from './../imports/api/Players'
import {Tracker} from 'meteor/tracker'

const renderPlayers = (playersList) => {
   return playersList.map((player)=> {
        return <p key={player._id}>{player.name} has {player.score} point(s).</p>;
    });
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    let playerName = e.target.playername.value;
    if (playerName){
        e.target.playerName.value = '';
        Players.insert ({
            name: playername,
            score: 0
        })
    }
}

Meteor.startup(() => {

    Tracker.autorun(() =>{
        let playersList = Players.find().fetch();
        let title = 'Score Keep';
        let name = 'Fateme';
        let jsx = (
            <div>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                {renderPlayers(playersList)}
                <form name="New-Player" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name="PlayerName" placeholder="player Name"/>
                    <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} value="add player"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
        ReactDom.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
    });

});
```

Comment: kindly share what issues your facing, and what have you tried so far to solve them.

Comment: thanks for your kindness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code e.target refers to the button which has an onClicked handler attached. To reference the input field value you can use plain Javascript or you do it the React way by using controlled components or uncontrolled components. If using plain Javascript, add an id to the input tag and reference it thus

```
  const playerName 
  =document.getElementById("idofiputtag").value;
```

PlayerName will contain the value in the textbox.